# 1 Activity/Multiple Fragments Approach: Set Different Themes for Different Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm almost dead finding a solution for this problem.

I just want to set WHITE color on one fragment and BLUE color for rest of the remaining fragments **(TALKING ABOUT STATUS BAR HERE)**. Have been searching for a solution for this since yesterday but not one seems to work. I've been suggested to **ContextWrapper** solution, **window.setStatusBarColor** solution but *they change the color for all of the fragments* and activity but I only want to change for one single fragment.

I really hope one of you could help!

Thanks